# How to change the form in which json returns the value to android?

Tags: php, android, json

Hi i have written an android app which uses mysql db my problem is that the php file returns the json object in the following format.

```
[
    [
        {
            "0": "1",
            "outlet_id": "1",
            "1": "Big Bazaar",
            "outlet_name": "Big Bazaar",
            "2": "12.9285690",
            "lat": "12.9285690",
            "3": "77.5831100",
            "lng": "77.5831100",
            "4": "images/BigBazaar.png",
            "outlet_image": "images/BigBazaar.png",
            "5": "Jayanagar 4th Block",
            "outlet_location": "Jayanagar 4th Block"
        }
    ]
]
```

But i need it to pass it in the following format.

```
[
    [
        {

            "outlet_id": "1",
            "outlet_name": "Big Bazaar",
            "lat": "12.9285690",
            "lng": "77.5831100",
            "outlet_image": "images/BigBazaar.png",
            "outlet_location": "Jayanagar 4th Block"
        }
    ]
]
```

This is my php code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

//$url = $_GET['url'];
//$mR = $_GET['mRequest'];
//$mOid = $_GET['mOutletId'];
//$mloc = $_GET['mLocation'];
//connect to the db
$user = "root";
$pswd = "";
$db = "recommendations_db";
$host = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db);
//if($mR == 'outlets' && $mloc = 'all'){
$query = "SELECT * FROM outlets";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $output[] = array($row); 
  }
print( json_encode($output) );
?>
```

How to get this output. Please help as i am poor in php.

Comment: It makes no difference between the clients, the json will still be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $output[] = array($row); 
}
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array`